# Perr/pɛr/ means peer/pɪə/, pair/peə/, or something else?

Tags: word-meaning, pronunciation, british-english, etymology, dialect

What do you mean by 'perr'/pɛr/? 'Peer'/pɪə/, pair/peə/ or something else? You know where that comes from? Is it a throaty pronunciation of the ‘r’ sound, characteristic of the Glaswegian accent of English?

https://www.scottishcorpus.ac.uk/document/?documentid=835

> “A couldny find a **perr** o yours that matched. Noo, wad ye pit a soak in it.”

https://books.google.cl/books?id=CjRYr5aA9aUC&pg=PA109&lpg=PA109&dq=perr+auld+cat&source=bl&ots=7YeD9lPN3F&sig=ACfU3U1f3tR9m7Xs8CqPQHxehUBaytxP3A&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjC9YeO9dTzAhV-H7kGHbs_B7IQ6AF6BAgoEAM

> We get a bit ay peace when the bar gets crowded and the **perr** old girl

https://dsldev.arts.gla.ac.uk/entry/dost/perr

> **Perr**, n. (? erron.: cf. Parpen n., Parpar, and Perk n.) —
> 1560–1 Edinb. Old Acc. I. 344.
> To the calsay maker for perris to be ane bacts to hald the peipill fre him and his wark;

https://arc.lib.montana.edu/ivan-doig/objects/2602-B019-F05.pdf

> Ah wis only nine stone four [130 pounds], an wi skin as
> white as the driven snaw an cheeks like a **perr** o roses.

https://onlinereadfreenovel.com/irvine-welsh/page,58,39649-skagboys.amp

> Just call the **perr** auld cat Eleanor Baxter … aw the lonely people, right enough.

https://allpoetry.com/poem/12096148-A-Glesca-Weans-Hogmanay-by-Jessie-McTavish

> Get oot mah road the **perr** of yous.

Comment: It's all Glaswegian dialect. Why do you mention the _Northumbrian_ accent?

Comment: @Old Brixtonian Because burr ends with "rr" but that's different. Thank you for the clarification!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some seem to be "pair" others "poor"

“A couldny find a perr o yours that matched

This looks like "pair". Pairs are two things that match in some way.

> I couldn't find a pair of yours that matched.

"...the perr old girl"

This looks like "poor". "Poor old (something)" is a common combination of adjectives.

"cheeks like a perr o roses."  = Pair of roses (cheeks come in pairs)

"perr auld cat"  = poor old cat.

"the perr of yous."  = the pair of you. (a comment directed at two people)

These dialect terms would only cause confusion if you used them in writing.

Comment: Poor in Scottish accents is often represented as 'puir'.